# Migrate from Sendmail to Postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail, hp-ux

We have an HP-UX environment running HP-UX 11.31. The system was originally built to send email out through Sendmail. The server only sends email out, and the programmer has built a number of programs using the `mailx` command to send the emails. We have decided to move from Sendmail to Postfix to fix some configuration issues and use an easier to configure program on the server.

We have installed and configured Postfix to work correctly, although when I run something like `echo "Hello World" | mailx -s "Hello World" $my_email`, and look at the routing information in the email headers, it seems that email route starts with Sendmail; from Sendmail to Postfix; then from Postfix to the recipient.

What I'm trying to understand is how to remove Sendmail from the routing and have `mailx` queue email directly with Postfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From HP support, I found that I had to tell `mailx` what binary to use to send mail by adding, in `/usr/share/lib/mailx.rc`, `set sendmail=/opt/iexpress/postfix/sbin/sendmail`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything; you're already using Postfix.

Postfix installs a binary called "sendmail" but that binary is using the postfix queueing system underneath.  It's standard practice for alternative mail delivery systems to provide a "sendmail" binary that provides minimal compatibility, this because so many mail frontend programs expect there to be a "sendmail" program to inject messages into the mail system.

Comment: I am aware of Postfix's binary, but I can actually see from the email headers that show the routing of the message that `mailx` first sends to the Sendmail program (not the binary of Postfix). See my answer on how I ultimately resolved the issue.